# Где можно узнать производительность AA-tree?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, дерево

Конкретно о производительности алгоритма, (средний, худший случай). Где можно узнать это?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, AA-tree отличается от красно-чёрных деревьев упрощением балансировок и уменьшением количества разных случаев. Значит, время работы такое же, как у RB - `O(logN)` для всех трёх базовых операций в среднем и худшем случае.

Вот и английская Вика подтверждает:

> Performance The performance of an AA tree **is equivalent to the
> performance of a red-black tree.** While an AA tree makes more
> rotations than a red-black tree, the simpler algorithms tend to be
> faster, and all of this balances out to result in similar performance.
> A red-black tree is more consistent in its performance than an AA
> tree, but an AA tree tends to be flatter, which results in slightly
> faster search times.